# iAd shared for UIViews

Tags: share, iad

I am using an iAd for sharing among views, but there are two strange issues which I have been browsing over the internet for solution without finding clue, therefore I post my question and code here for brain storming.

.h:
    @interface AppDelegate : NSObject  {
    UIWindow *window;
    ADBannerView *adBanner;

```
appViewController *viewControllerApp;
}
```

.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adBanner.currentContentSizeIdentifier =ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
adBanner.delegate = self;
adBanner.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
adBanner.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[window addSubview:viewControllerApp.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}

appViewController.m
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
//#ifdef LITE_VERSION
    [SharedAdBannerView  setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 0, 0)];
    [self.view addSubview:SharedAdBannerView];
//#ifdef
}
```

somewhere in the appViewController.m:

```
{....
    playGameView = [[PlayGameViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlayGameViewController"
        bundle:nil];
    [self.view insertSubview:playGameView.view atIndex:10];
}
```

So, there are two questions:
1. when the App is running, the iAd isn't displayed on the right position (shall be 
0,40,0,0) but it doesn't show up unless I changed the position to (0,180,0,0), but it 
actually wasn't on the 0,180. it looks like on 0,40.

1. When I move to 2nd view (PlayGameView), then click on the iAd, the iAd shows a full 
   screen View, then I close the iAd, the screen of PlayGameView was gone! it was replaced by
   the rootView!! how can I close the iAd with the PlayGameView stays?

I don't see problem at rootView when the iAd is clicked and closed.. anyone can help will be
 highly highly appreciated!

BR
Georg

Answer (score 0):

ok, now I have finally found the problem,  I replaced this

```
[self presentModalViewController:playGameView animated:NO];
```

from

```
[self.view insertSubview:playGameView.view atIndex:10];
```

then it work perfectlly.

now there is only one remain issue: position of iAd banner view